# Bare Metal Cloud - Python SDK SSL/TLS exception

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-python-sdk

When trying to use the BMCS Python SDK, I get an SSL/TLS exception. Why?

Exception:
`[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bare Metal Cloud Services requires TLS 1.2 connections. Your version of OpenSSL is probably too old and does not support TLS 1.2. Please upgrade your version of OpenSSL and try again.